# Getting error while using group by in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Getting error when trying to use group by for update statement

```
Update LegMove
set   Event_Code =  max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Status_Description else NULL end),                                                  
      Create_Date = max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,l.Move_Create_Timestamp),0) else NULL end), 
      PTimeStamp=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Move_Create_Timestamp else NULL end), 
      Acrual_Date=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,l.Move_Status_Timestamp),0) else NULL end), 
      Actual_TimeStamp=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Move_Status_Timestamp else NULL end) , 
      Reason_Code=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Move_Reason_Code else NULL end) , 
      Create_User=max(case when m.Status_Description = 'DPKL' then l.Move_Created_User else NULL end) from wrkLegMove m inner join MovementMaster l with(nolock) on l.Leg_Key = m.Leg_Key and l.Status_Description = m.Status_Description and l.Move_Create_Timestamp = m. FirstMoveTimewhere m.Status_Description in ('DPKL') 
group by m.Leg_Key, l.Shipment_Number, l.Shipment_Leg_Sequence
```

Comment: An `UPADTE` can't use a `GROUP BY`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: It is SQL server . I have used CTE but is running more time